# Scraping different URL´s and specific line with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i try to scrape the the symbols of this site: https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EDJI?p=%5EDJI

And then i try to get the Volume for every Symbol from the specific detail site like: https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/HON?p=HON

The problem is, that it get the "quote/HON?p=HON" but could not add it to the url "https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/"

The second problem is, that i don't know how to get the "Volume" from the detail site, for example from this site: https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/HON?p=HON

I tried many thinks but don't know how to solve this problems..

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = ['https://de.finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EIXIC/components?p=%5EIXIC',
        'https://de.finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EDJI/components?p=%5EDJI',
        'https://de.finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EGSPC/components?p=%5EGSPC']

current_date = datetime.now()

header = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36'}

stock_information_yahoo_finance = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name', 'Volume', 'Volume2'])
stock_symbols = []

for url in urls:

    r: requests.Response = requests.get(url, headers=header)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    for item in soup.select('tr.BdT'):
        stock_symbols.append(item.select_one('a').text)

for symbol in sorted(stock_symbols):
    r = requests.get("https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/" + symbol)
    detailed_soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
    summary_info = detailed_soup.find('div', {'id': 'quote-summary'})
    name = detailed_soup.find_all("h1", {"class": "D(ib) Fz(18px)"})

    try:
        for td_tag in summary_info.find('table'):
            span_tag = td_tag.findAll('span', {'class': 'Trsdu(0.3s)'})
            volume = span_tag[4].text
            avg_volume = span_tag[5].text
            volume = volume.replace(",", "")
            avg_volume = avg_volume.replace(",", "")
            volume = int(volume)
            avg_volume = int(avg_volume)
            volume2 = avg_volume * 2
            stock_information_yahoo_finance = stock_information_yahoo_finance.append({ 'Name' : name,
                'Volume': volume, 'Volume2': volume2}, ignore_index=True)
    except:
        volume = '0'
        avg_volume = '0'
        volume2 = '0'
        stock_information_yahoo_finance = stock_information_yahoo_finance.append({
            'Volume': volume, 'Volume2': volume2}, ignore_index=True)

stocks2 = stock_information_yahoo_finance.loc[
          stock_information_yahoo_finance['Volume'] > stock_information_yahoo_finance['Volume2'], :]

print(stocks2.to_string())
```

Comment: where are you getting the "href" in this statement - r = requests.get("https://de.finance.yahoo.com/" + 'href')

Comment: That was a test.. i tried also with r = requests.get("de.finance.yahoo.com" + "Test") (In list i saved the urls) but didn't work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do.  The code below scrapes this URL: https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EIXIC/components?p=%5EIXIC and extract the company symbols from the table.  The symbols are added to a list, which is used to query for additional data points on the individual pages. Those data points can be added to a dictionary, list or dataframe.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EIXIC/components?p=%5EIXIC'


header = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36'}


stock_symbols = []

r: requests.Response = requests.get(url, headers=header)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
for item in soup.select('tr.BdT'):
    stock_symbols.append(item.select_one('a').text)


for symbol in sorted(stock_symbols):
    r = requests.get("https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/" + symbol)
    detailed_soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
    summary_info = detailed_soup.find('div', {'id': 'quote-summary'})
    span_tag = summary_info.findAll('span', {'class': 'Trsdu(0.3s)'})
    previous_close = span_tag[0].text
    open_price = span_tag[1].text
    bid_price = span_tag[2].text
    ask_price = span_tag[3].text
    volume = span_tag[4].text
    avg_volume = span_tag[5].text
```

Here is an example that saved the stock information to a Pandas dataframe.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep
from random import randint
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EIXIC/components?p=%5EIXIC'

current_date = datetime.now()


header = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36'}

stock_information_yahoo_finance = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date', 'Symbol', 'Previous Close Price', 'Open Price',
                                                        'Bid Price', 'Ask Price', 'Volume', 'Average Volume'])
stock_symbols = []

r: requests.Response = requests.get(url, headers=header)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
for item in soup.select('tr.BdT'):
    stock_symbols.append(item.select_one('a').text)


for symbol in sorted(stock_symbols):
    r = requests.get("https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/" + symbol)
    detailed_soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
    summary_info = detailed_soup.find('div', {'id': 'quote-summary'})
    span_tag = summary_info.findAll('span', {'class': 'Trsdu(0.3s)'})
    previous_close = span_tag[0].text
    open_price = span_tag[1].text
    bid_price = span_tag[2].text
    ask_price = span_tag[3].text
    volume = span_tag[4].text
    avg_volume = span_tag[5].text

    stock_information_yahoo_finance = stock_information_yahoo_finance.append({
            'Date': current_date.strftime("%m-%d-%Y"), 'Symbol': symbol, 'Previous Close Price': previous_close,
            'Open Price': open_price, 'Bid Price':  bid_price, 'Ask Price': ask_price, 'Volume': volume,
            'Average Volume': avg_volume}, ignore_index=True)
    
    # add random delay to prevent Yahoo Finance from blocking requests
    sleep(randint(1, 5))

print(stock_information_yahoo_finance.to_string())
#output 
          Date Symbol Previous Close Price Open Price      Bid Price      Ask Price      Volume Average Volume
0   02-17-2021   ACCD                53.76      53.69   50.02 x 1000    52.99 x 800     612,444        704,749
1   02-17-2021   AGLE                 7.27       7.27     7.35 x 900    7.30 x 1100     204,802        224,822
2   02-17-2021   ATEC                16.67      16.56   16.43 x 1100   16.45 x 3100     437,393        847,203
3   02-17-2021    BBI               1.6000     1.5600  1.5000 x 3200  1.5200 x 1000   2,730,143      4,035,214
4   02-17-2021    BBQ                 6.36       6.44    6.00 x 1300    6.39 x 1100       5,701         16,236
5   02-17-2021   CIIC                27.34      27.10   26.85 x 2200    27.50 x 800   1,086,149      4,664,344
6   02-17-2021   CVCO               215.00     213.29   215.87 x 800  252.20 x 2200      21,097         42,231
7   02-17-2021   EXAS               154.28     148.95  142.10 x 1400  145.45 x 1800   5,246,528      1,724,611
8   02-17-2021   FARM                 6.59       6.59     6.72 x 800    6.76 x 1000     177,308        197,201
9   02-17-2021   FARO                79.73      78.87    78.25 x 800    77.93 x 800     101,062         87,798
10  02-17-2021   FEYE                21.07      20.98    20.54 x 900   20.70 x 2200   6,727,862      9,450,016
11  02-17-2021   FNKO                13.08      13.14    12.57 x 900    13.48 x 800     444,766        773,173
12  02-17-2021   FNLC                24.89      24.80    24.81 x 800   26.00 x 1000       8,143         15,695
13  02-17-2021   FRSX                10.00       9.75     9.60 x 800     9.66 x 900   4,063,999     14,712,591
14  02-17-2021   FRTA                21.68      21.41   21.76 x 1100    21.78 x 800     233,758        432,391
15  02-17-2021   IFRX                 6.22       6.12     6.31 x 800    6.32 x 1000     320,425        329,272
16  02-17-2021   NEBC                10.75      10.88    10.46 x 800   10.87 x 1300     766,067        380,736
17  02-17-2021   NMRD                 8.04       7.71     7.35 x 900    7.50 x 1400     289,880        212,036
18  02-17-2021   NMRK                 8.65       8.51    8.73 x 2200    8.74 x 1200     706,172        933,298
19  02-17-2021   NVCN               2.2600     2.2500  2.1000 x 3200  2.1100 x 4000  17,213,552      5,553,301
20  02-17-2021   NVCR               185.31     182.65   173.80 x 900   181.30 x 800     524,242        957,014
21  02-17-2021   OLMA                48.55      50.33   47.50 x 1000   54.50 x 1000     152,455        157,635
22  02-17-2021   OPTT               5.0200     4.9300  4.6600 x 1100  4.6900 x 3200   6,398,491     11,193,375
23  02-17-2021   SCOA                10.45      10.49   10.38 x 2200    10.40 x 800     263,090        455,133
24  02-17-2021   SCOR               3.8800     3.8600  3.8100 x 1000  3.8600 x 3200     572,379        724,314
25  02-17-2021    SDC                12.43      12.50   12.23 x 3000   12.24 x 3000   6,077,952      6,864,586
26  02-17-2021    SDH               5.0800     4.9900  4.8100 x 1000  5.0500 x 1000     225,981        960,750
27  02-17-2021   SLAB               153.75     150.87  150.00 x 1100  150.02 x 1000     338,618        270,232
28  02-17-2021   TSLA               796.22     779.09   793.65 x 800  793.71 x 1300  26,078,898     43,111,968
29  02-17-2021   TWST               156.25     155.00  153.00 x 1000  154.61 x 1000     981,909        814,265
```

Comment: Hey, thats awesome and exactly what i need! Thanks! But when is use you code i get this error:     volume = span_tag[4].text
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I think its because the market is not opened and it could not get a volume? but why is does not let the volume empty?

Comment: @BerndKlaus I did some troubleshooting and noted that some of the values were missing when I tested the code prior to 9am EST.  I double checked my code and removed two excess lines. The dataframe was being populated with all the data after 9am.  If needed I can do some more troubleshooting.

Comment: @BerndKlaus I also added a random delay to the Python requests, because sometimes a source will block your connection if you hit it too fast and the delay will helps mitigate that somewhat.

Comment: Hello, yes but it did not work for me. Same error. I could fix it now with try and except. Every time it could not find a value for volume or / and avg. volume, i set it to 0. But thanks for you help! You helped me a lot! i updated my code in the main post, so you can see my solution

Comment: @BerndKlaus.  Thanks for accepting the answer.   I will look at the code again and update my answer if I can improve it some.

Answer (score 0):

it better to use new method `.select()` and `.select_one()`, it compatible with CSS selector and you can debug it in browser (F12). see image below to get the volume

[image]

simple explaination about CSS selector:

- `.` dot is for class
- `#` is for ID
- `tr.BdT` select tagname `tr` with class `BdT`
- `td[data-test="TD_VOLUME-value"]` select tagname `td` that has attribute `data-test="TD_VOLUME-value"`

the code

```
data = {
  'Symbol': [],
  'Volume': []
}

for item in soup.select('tr.BdT'):
    symbol = item.select_one('a').text
    data["Symbol"].append(symbol)

    r = requests.get("https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/" + symbol)
    detailed_soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

    data["Volume"] = detailed_soup.select_one('td[data-test="TD_VOLUME-value"]').text

print(data)
```